# Showing a div depending on flag image clicked

Tags: jquery, html

So at the moment I have 4 different flags which I want to show one of four divs. For example, if I click the French flag, I want to show the French content, and hide the other language divs etc.

At the moment I have four flags with the IDs of french, german, english and dutch and when the are clicked, I get the ID of the flag which was clicked and use that name to toggle the div that I want shown.

```
$("img").click(function () {
 var myClass = $(this).attr("id");

   $('div.' + myClass).toggle();

 });
});
```

The associated classes of the divs are also called english, dutch, german and french.

The problem I'm having is being able to hide the divs that I haven't clicked as I get a page full of four divs!

Thank you.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Maybe add an extra class to all divs so you can hide them at once and show only the selected one.

Comment: Without HTML we *cannot* answer this question without making guesses or assumptions. Please show it to us. Ideally *also* show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/). The basic notion is that you should try to help *us* to help *you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the classes are called fixed and called `english, dutch, german and french` then

```
var $divs = $('.english, .dutch, .german, .french');
$("img").click(function () {
    var myClass = this.id;
    var $div = $('div.' + myClass).toggle();

    $divs.not($div).hide()

 });
});
```

another solution is to add another class called `flag` to all the 4 divs like `<div class="flag english">...</div>` then

```
var $divs = $('.flag');
$("img").click(function () {
    var $div = $divs.filter('.' + this.id).toggle();
    $divs.not($div).hide()

 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for a simple tab functionality, so I'd rethink your markup and use classes to define both the flags and the languages. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flag english" data-language="english">E</div>
<div class="flag dutch" data-language="dutch">D</div>
<div class="flag german" data-language="german">G</div>
<div class="flag french" data-language="french">F</div>

<article class="language english show">
    English content
</article>
<article class="language dutch">
    Nederlandse inhoud
</article >
<article class="language german">
    Deutsch Inhalt
</article>
<article class="language french">
    Contenu en français
</article>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var langs = $(".language");
var flags = $(".flag");
flags.on("click", function(e){
    var lang = $(this).data("language");
    langs.filter(".show").removeClass("show");
    langs.filter("." + lang).addClass("show");
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fd3rX/3/).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<div class="english lang">...</div>
<div class="german lang">...</div>

$("img").click(function () {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("id");
   $('div.lang').hide();
   $('div.' + myClass).show();
});
```